# Why is the query not returning values?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am in middle of migrating my perl script from older version to Perl version (v5.16.3) from  v5.8.4  and ran into an issue where the query is not fetching results.

Tested following scenarios when query returns

- Multiple row, single column -> Worked fine
- single row, single column  -> worked fine
- Multiple rows, multiple columns -> not working
- single row, multiple columns -> not working

Not sure what's happening. it's not throwing error but just returning 0 records

```
my $sth;
        my $prepareCapture = capture_merged
        {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($self->{_generatedSQL});
        };
        $self->addProcessLogMessage($prepareCapture) if defined $prepareCapture;
        if (!defined $sth)
        {
            $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: DBI::errstr = ' . $DBI::errstr);
            $self->addErrorMessage('PWX.extractPWXFile', 'Prepare of generated SQL against the PWX database failed');
            return -1;
        }
        
        # Execute generated SQL against the PWX database
        $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: Executing generated SQL against PWX database');
        my $executeRC;
        my $executeCapture = capture_merged 
        {
            $executeRC = $sth->execute();
        };
        
        $self->addProcessLogMessage(sprintf('[PWX.Debugging sth Value-->%s',$sth));
        $self->addProcessLogMessage(sprintf('[PWX.Debugging executeCapture -->%s',$executeCapture));    
        $self->addProcessLogMessage(sprintf('[PWX.Debugging executeRC Val -->%s',$executeRC));  

        $self->addProcessLogMessage($executeCapture) if defined $executeCapture;
        if (!defined $executeRC)
        {
            $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: DBI::errstr = ' . $DBI::errstr);
            $self->addErrorMessage('PWX.extractPWXFile', 'Execution of generated SQL against the PWX database failed');
            return -1;
        }
        
        # Store details in local variables
        my $exportFileNm = PCF::Helpers::PathHelper->resolveExportFile($self->{_srcSysCd},$self->{_fileNm});
        my $fileDelimiter = $self->{_fileDelimiter};
        my $fileDetailType = $self->{_fileDetailType};
        my $recordCount = 0;
        # Open the export file, ready for writing to
        $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: Opening target object file');
        $self->addProcessLogMessage(sprintf('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: Export File = %s', $exportFileNm));
        if (open(EXPORT_HANDLE, sprintf('> %s', $exportFileNm)))
        {
            # Output Header Record
            $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: Outputting Header Record to target object file');
            print EXPORT_HANDLE $self->{_fileHeaderType}
                              , $fileDelimiter
                              , $self->{_fileRunNbr}
                              , $fileDelimiter
                              , $self->{_fileRunDt}
                              , $fileDelimiter
                              , $self->{_fileDescription}
                              , $fileDelimiter
                              , $self->{_runtimeParameters}->{'ProcInstId'}
                              , "\n";
            
            # Fetch the resultset and output a Detail Record
            my $refRowArray;
            my $colIndex;
            my $colData;
            my $colOutput;
            my $colOutput1;
            my $colOutput2;
            my $colOutput3;
            $self->addProcessLogMessage('[PWX.extractPWXFile]: Outputting Detail Record(s) to target object file');
            while (1)
            {
                $refRowArray = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
                last if !defined $refRowArray;
                
        # Iterate through the columns and build a hash for output
                print EXPORT_HANDLE $fileDetailType;
                $colIndex = 0;
                $colOutput1 = '';
                $colOutput2 = '';
                $colOutput3 = '';                
                foreach $colData (@$refRowArray)
                {
                    # Perform left and right TRIM inline
                    $colOutput = $colData;
                    $colOutput =~ s/^\s+//;
                    $colOutput =~ s/\s+$//;
                    
                    # Replace CRLF, CR, LF and Pipes with a space
                    $colOutput =~ s/(\r\n|\r|\n|\|)/ /g;
                    
                    # If the column data has not returned a NULL value
                    # but rather contains all blanks then output a single blank
                    if ((defined $colData)
                         && (length($colOutput) == 0))
                    {
                        $colOutput = ' ';
                    }
                    
                    # If the first column, which is DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP, format into ANSI standard
                    # Does not apply to sources that have EffStrtTs, RecTpCd as first 2 columns.
                    if ($colIndex == 0 && $self->{_srcHasProcCols} eq 'N')
                    {
                        $colOutput = substr($colOutput, 0, 4)
                                   . '-'
                                   . substr($colOutput, 4, 2)
                                   . '-'
                                   . substr($colOutput, 6, 2)
                                   . ' '
                                   . substr($colOutput, 8, 2)
                                   . ':'
                                   . substr($colOutput, 10, 2)
                                   . ':'
                                   . substr($colOutput, 12, 2)
                                   . '.'
                                   . substr($colOutput, 14, 6);
                    }
                    # If the extract is incremental, substitute capx_action values of "I" and "U" for "M"
                    elsif (($incrementalLoad == 1) && ($colIndex == 1))
                    {
                        if ($colOutput eq 'I' || $colOutput eq 'U')
                        {
                            $colOutput = 'M';
                        }
                    }
                    
                    # If the extract is bulk VSAM DFSORT, substitute RecTpCd value 'F' with the derived value from REC_TYP_CDE column.
                    # REC_TYP_CDE column is at the end of the record, so do not write to file until end of record is reached.
                    if ($attrDfSortFlag eq 'Y')
                    {
                       #keep the column values in two strings
                       if ($colIndex > 1)
                       {
                          $colOutput3 .= $fileDelimiter . $colOutput;
                       }
                       elsif ($colIndex == 0)
                       {
                          $colOutput1 = $colOutput;
                       }
                       
                       if ($colIndex == $#$refRowArray)
                       {
                          #derive RecTpCd value: 1 insert, 2 update, 3 delete
                          if (($colOutput == 1) || ($colOutput == 2))
                          {
                             $colOutput2 = 'M';
                          }
                          elsif ($colOutput == 3)
                          {
                             $colOutput2 = 'D';
                          }
                          else 
                          {   
                     if (!defined $colOutput)
                     {
                                $colOutput2 = 'Null';
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                $colOutput2 = $colOutput;
                             }
                             
                     $self->addErrorMessage('PWX.extractPWXFile', "VSAM DFSORT File: Invalid REC_TYP_CDE value from source. expecting 1,2 or 3 but received $colOutput2");
                     return -1;
                          }
                          
                          #append the strings to make the record
                          print EXPORT_HANDLE $fileDelimiter, $colOutput1, $fileDelimiter, $colOutput2, $colOutput3;
                       }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       print EXPORT_HANDLE $fileDelimiter, $colOutput;
                    }
                    
                    # Increment the column counter
                    $colIndex++;
                }
                print EXPORT_HANDLE "\n";
                
                # Increment the record counter
                $recordCount++;
            }

           # Check if there is any error while fetching. fail if there is.
       if ($DBI::err)
       {
           $self->addErrorMessage('PWX.extractPWXFile', "Connection to database lost due to following error: $DBI::errstr");
           $self->addErrorMessage('PWX.extractPWXFile', "The following number of records were extracted before exiting : $recordCount ");
           return -1;
       }
```

Query:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12,
        col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22
FROM mmm.cont
WHERE  datets >= DATEADD(HOUR,-2,'2021-06-17 14:30:40.110000')
AND datets < '2021-07-22 20:05:32.620000'
AT ISOLATION READ COMMITTED
```

Comment: Please show all the Perl code, not just the loop. Show the code that calls the query to set `$sth`.  What error-checking are you doing?

Comment: Seems a bit strange to update to a version of Perl that's eight years old. Why not upgrade to something more recent?

Comment: Added full code

Answer (score 1):

> returning 0 records

How do you know that? The code that you show us does nothing different if it returns some rows or no rows. I suspect that you're over-simplifying your code in order to share it with us and, in the process, removing the bit that is causing your problem.

I don't think it causes your problem, but I'll just point out that your current code can be simplified to:

```
while ($refRowArray = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
  # do nothing
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I have put some logs which prints count of records returned. In this case its not returning any records. However, if I replace that with simple query say which I know will return 1 record then the logging also indicates its retuning record and also inside the while loop I am writing to a file so it is writing to file as well.

Comment: Even if I replace 2 columns in select query instead of 1 with simple query even then its failing. if Select query has more than 1 column then its not returning anything from db.

Comment: Hello, Any help on this is highly appreciated. I am new to perl script and unable to proceed. Please help!!!